# Installing window problem with new laptop having old Window in it

Tags: laptop, boot, installation, sony-vaio

I bought a new Sony vaio VPCEB15PA laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium installed in it. I want to install Windows 7 Ultimate and also want to make multiple partitions. But when I put Windows 7 ultimate DVD in DVD rom and reboot it but it donot get boot from DVD rom but load the old Windows 7 Home. I also change the first boot device option to external boot rather then from HD. but it never does. is there any other process to do that as I want to install Windows 7 ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first boot device should be your CD/DVD Drive. Can you confirm this (double check)?
Is it possible that the Windows 7 Ultimate DVD is not bootable?
When the system boots, do you see any message "Booting from CD Rom Failed" (or something similar)?

Comment: NO... CD is boot able because I tried the same DVD on my other PC and it works And it did not give any message while loading but loads the existing window 7 Home and do not get the boot from DVD rom.